# Size-dependent \big-, \Big- (etc.) modifiers

Tags: delimiters

What I'm looking for is a way to use `\big` and its friends such that they adapt to the environment that they're in, e.g. `\scriptstyle`. To a degree, this was already covered [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87456) and the corresponding [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87505/42225), but the results are not yet as I'd hope.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\tbo}{\tilde{b}+1}

\begin{document}

\[ \left(\tbo\right)^{\left(\tbo\right)^{\left(\tbo\right)}} \]
\vspace{-0.5cm}
\[ \bigl(\tbo\bigr)^{\bigl(\tbo\bigr)^{\bigl(\tbo\bigr)}} \]

% Bruno Le Floch's modification (see answer linked above)
\makeatletter
\let\bBigg@@\bBigg@
\renewcommand{\bBigg@}[2]{{%
  \mathchoice
    {\bBigg@@{#1}{#2}}%
    {\bBigg@@{#1}{#2}}%
    {\big@size=.7\big@size\bBigg@@{#1}{#2}}%
    {\big@size=.5\big@size\bBigg@@{#1}{#2}}}}%
\makeatother

\vspace{-0.5cm}
\[ \bigl(\tbo\bigr)^{\bigl(\tbo\bigr)^{\bigl(\tbo\bigr)}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image: big]

The modification improves the sizing a bit, but not substantially (especially in the `\scriptscriptstyle`). Also, the horizontal spacing in the small styles is a bit wide for my taste. I tried playing around with the factors `0.7` and `0.5` a bit, but this didn't change anything (to the bare eye).

I don't know if it's too much to ask, but I'd hope that it's possible to mimic the behaviour of `\big` for normal text as closely as possible also for the superscripts.

In a perfect world, a solution would also take into account what David Carlisle's comment to the answer linked above mentioned, namely preventing the scaling to be too small for smaller font sizes. However, I don't know how to read NFSS data, and neither whether this could be done dynamically...

Comment: I'm not sure whether bigger delimiters are good in such a case. To be honest, I'm sure they aren't.

Comment: I tend to agre with @egreg . If anything, I would consider putting the largest one in `\bigl(...\bigr)` to make it a bit larger since it has a large exponent, but that depends a lot on the context, too.

Comment: @egreg: Well, the example here is contrived for demonstration purposes, but I have use cases where standard brackets are too small, left/right is too big, and \big would be fine if it behaved as in normal mode. Or do you mean "using `\big` in sub/superscripts  is not good" in general?

Comment: @Axel Stacking complicated exponents is usually not recommended, because it hinders readability.

Comment: I agree with @egreg, there is no reason to scale the fences here. It is fully clear what they fence in, and there is no need for them to vertically cover the tilde.

Comment: @egreg, I don't dispute your recommendation, but such cases do occur (an expression doesn't have to be overly complicated to incorporate a fence, e.g. `\lceil\tilde b\rceil`). Again, my example was for demonstration purposes (similarly in this comment) - I would certainly try to avoid such expressions in supersuperscripts - but I am interested in commands that are as universal as possible. In particular, since I like the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`-command from `mathtools`, having an adapted version of `\big` is relevant to me to be able to use e.g. `\ceil[\big]{\tilde b}` also in superscripts.

Comment: In CM fonts, I like `\lceil \tilde b \rceil` better than adding `\big`, adding just the `\big` and the tilde sort of disappear in the noise.

Comment: @daleif: I can't seem to get across the point that these are merely illustrations which are intentionally kept simple (I didn't even compile the `\ceil`-example with `\tilde`). Even so, I contend that everyone on StackExchange strives (possibly among other things) for beautifully set math, and as so often is the case with beauty, there are different opinions - why can't I decide for myself?

Comment: @Axel, remember that a lot of other users search this site for solutions. We do not want them to get into bad habits that we later on have to spend a lot a time explaining to them that the solution that they copied was not a good solution in general.

Comment: @daleif, I'm of course willing to accept a TeXnical reason why this is discouraged, but so far, the critiques were only about stylistic aspects (except tohecz' comment to Steven's answer about the math axis, which I agree with).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative:  the `\scaleleftright` macro of the `scalerel` package.  It will scale the 1st and third argument to the vertical extent of the second argument (without the requirement imposed by `\left` `\right` of centering about the math axis).

To respond to the criticism of tohecz and a query by the OP, one can compensate for the unbalanced math axis by adding a "strut" that conforms to the font size AND obeys the math axis.  Here, I show a result demonstrating the point of tohecz, first without such a strut, and then with a strut.  The strut is a `\vphantom` of a left paren in the current math size, scaled to 130% size (that size can be changed if what needs to be enclosed is of larger/smaller vertical extent).  The paren is symmetric about the math axis, and so therefore is `\mstrut`.  The size of the paren in the current math style is imported to the `\scalebox` by using the `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` construct  of `scalerel`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand{\tbo}{\tilde{b}+1}

\begin{document}

\[ \scaleleftright{(}{\tbo}{)}^{{\scaleleftright{(}{a_j - 1}{)}}%
  ^{\scaleleftright{(}{\tbo}{)}}}
\]

\renewcommand{\tbo}{\tilde{b}+1\mstrut}
\newcommand\mstrut{\ThisStyle{\vphantom{\scalebox{1.3}{$\SavedStyle($}}}}

\[ \scaleleftright{(}{\tbo}{)}^{{\scaleleftright{(}{a_j - 1\mstrut}{)}}%
  ^{\scaleleftright{(}{\tbo}{)}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: $\scaleleftright{(}{\tilde b+1}{)}\scaleleftright{(}{a_j-1}{)}$ will very likely give a very confusing result. There _is_ a good reason why math axis exists, it's not something Knuth implemented while being on LSD.

Comment: @tohecz  I understand the argument of math axes, and don't disagree with you.  Nonetheless, there arise situations where breaking the rules can occasionally make sense.  Perhaps this is one.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, thanks for the response; visually it is pretty muched what I imagined, but it still has the problem (feature?) of adjusting to the height of the content (which may not always be desired). In terms of the math axis, is there a way to expand away from it in both directions equally (sort of like the inverse of `\smash`), such that one doesn't have to manually adjust the struts for different content? Or even better, a version of the macro which respects the math axis?

Comment: @Axel  The problem with the default way it is done is that, when in sub-sub-script mode, things like `1ex` do not shrink accordingly, nor do things like `\strut`.  The way to remedy that is to define a "strut" that is based on the current math size, as I have done in tohecz-inspired update.  While I chose that strut somewhat arbitrarily, based on what was being typeset, one could choose a strut that obeys the math axis AND scales with the font size, such as `\newcommand\mstrut{\ThisStyle{\vphantom{\scalebox{1.1}{$\SavedStyle($}}}}`.  Perhpas I'll update my answer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, thanks again for your answer. It's not exactly what I had in mind, but I'll try it out and have accepted your answer.