# Outputting effective size of \left(...\right) parentheses

Tags: parentheses

I am trying to get rid of `\left(` and `\right)` in my document while maintaining the mostly appropriate size of parentheses. However, there are maybe a couple dozen (or more) occurrences, and I would like to avoid going through the document bazillion times, trying out `\big`, `\Big` and the like for each one and repeatedly compiling. So I thought that maybe I could redefine `\left(` to output a warning to indicate

1. that I am using it and should not, and
2. the effective size of the current `\left(...\right)` construct to easy replacements.

I know that `mathtools` has a `\delimsize`, but I this can only be used with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`.

Is this possible?

Something that would already help me: where are `\left` and `\right` actually defined?

Comment: "I am trying to get rid of \left( and \right) in my document while maintaining the mostly appropriate size of parentheses." Eh... why would you want to do that?

Comment: @wythagoras one example out of many on TeX.SX: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31526/macro-for-left-and-right/58641#58641

Comment: @wythagoras another reason is that I feel like `\left(...\right)`should not consider accents such as `\tilde` etc., and I am getting tired of fighting the side-effects of `\smash` every time I use `U` and `\tilde{U}`, for example.  Compare `$\left(U\right. \left(\tilde{U}\right.$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your text editor change all occurrences of `\left` to either `\xleft` or `\yleft`, depending on which of these two methods you prefer.  Then, any time a `\left` is invoked, an `\fbox` showing `$\big#1\Big#1\bigg#1\Bigg#1$` is laid to the left of the construct.

This is a flag for you to do something about it.  You can visually see if any of the 4 "big" constructs are the right size, and either edit that `\xleft` or `\yleft` to either the appropriate big delimiter of change it back to `\left` if none of them work.

The only difference between `\xleft` and `\yleft` is that the `\yleft` will `\smash` the `\fbox`.  This is useful if nested `\left`ing occurs, otherwise the `\fbox` alters the natural size of the outer `\left`s.  The downside of `\yleft` is that it allows overlap to occur, which can be a bit confusing until the resolution is made.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\xleft#1#2\right{
  \fbox{$\big#1\Big#1\bigg#1\Bigg#1$}\left#1#2\right}
\def\yleft#1#2\right{
  \smash{\fbox{$\big#1\Big#1\bigg#1\Bigg#1$}}\left#1#2\right}
\begin{document}
Here is the \verb|\yleft| method which smashes the test box.
\[
y = \yleft( x^2 + 3\right)
\]
And now for the next test:
\[
y = \yleft(\frac{a}{b}\right)
\]
Finally:
\[
y = 3\yleft(\frac{\yleft( x^2 + 3\right)}{b}\right)
\]
Here is the \verb|\xleft| method which does not smash the test box.
\[
y = \xleft( x^2 + 3\right)
\]
And now for the next test:
\[
y = \xleft(\frac{a}{b}\right)
\]
Finally:
\[
y = 3\xleft(\frac{\xleft( x^2 + 3\right)}{b}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

For a dimension-based approach, invoke `\basesizes` at the beginning of the document to see the vertical dimension of `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` and `\Bigg`.  Then change all `\left` to `\zleft` to reveal the required size for the given construct.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\def\zleft#1#2\right{
  \smash{\ThisStyle{\setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle\left#1#2\right.$}%
  \edef\tmp{\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax}%
  \fbox{\expandafter\truncate\expandafter{\tmp}}}}%
  \left#1#2\right}
\newcommand\truncate[1]{\truncateaux#1\relax}
\def\truncateaux#1.#2\relax{#1pt}
\newcommand\basesizes{%
  \noindent big: \setbox0=\hbox{\big(}\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax\par
  \noindent Big: \setbox0=\hbox{\Big(}\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax\par
  \noindent bigg: \setbox0=\hbox{\bigg(}\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax\par
  \noindent Bigg: \setbox0=\hbox{\Bigg(}\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0\relax\par
}
\begin{document}
\basesizes
Here is the \verb|\zleft| method which smashes the test box.
\[
y = \zleft( x^2 + 3\right)
\]
And now for the next test:
\[
y = \zleft(\frac{a}{b}\right)
\]
Finally:
\[
y = 3\zleft(\frac{\zleft( x^2 + 3\right)}{b}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, beautiful! I was kind of focused on measuring the height of the box and converting that to `\big`, `\Big`, ... - but just putting all of them next to the group is just as good. Thank you!

Comment: @bers I have added an addendum, if you prefer the dimension-based approach.

Comment: Wow, that's impressive. I have met one curiosity, though: Which parentheses should I choose when your dimension code tells me that the current parentheses are 10pt in height? `$ a^{ \zleft( x^2 \right) } $` is one example. `(` is too small, `\big(` is too big - compare `$ a^{ ( x^2 ) } $ (too small), $ a^{ \big( x^2 \big )} $ (too big)`. Do I need to manually scale `\big` to `superscript` size?

Comment: @bers I don't know how best to handle that situation to that level of precision.  I would likely just choose the next size up.  One option, which would be a pain to recode your equations, would be to choose the closest big size and place it inside of the `\scaleleftright` or `\stretchleftright` macro (`scalerel` package), as in `$ a^{ \scaleleftright{(}{\mathstrut  x^2}{)} } $`.

Comment: @bers See `$ a^{ ( x^2 ) } + a^{  \left( x^2 \right) } + a^{ \scaleleftright{(}{\mathstrut x^2}{)} } $`

Comment: @bers See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87456/in-exponents-parenthesis-too-small-big-too-big and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150355/size-dependent-big-big-etc-modifiers

Comment: Awesome,  thanks. I just hope I won't need that too often ;)